# Push notifications for both android and iPhone

Tags: android, iphone, push-notification

I m developing an android and iPhone app and wanted to send push notification both platform users - a simple pop up with any major news preferably even when the device is closed.

Any suggestions which way I should go for?

Comment: Do You need some way to send notifications to both platforms? Then, probably http://urbanairship.com can do the trick

Comment: I have a rails server and a backend. Is it possible to send a push message using my rails server to both iPhone and android app?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can configure your app and send out push notifications to both Android and iOS (as well as to four more platforms) with [PushWoosh](http://pushwoosh.com). Unlike Urban Airship, it's a free service so that you don't have to pay and integration is pretty easy.

They have several extensive guides on how to integrate push notifications in your app, for instance: [iOS](http://www.pushwoosh.com/programming-push-notification/ios/ios-configuration-guide/), [Android](http://www.pushwoosh.com/programming-push-notification/android/android-gcm-api-configuration/)

Answer (score 4):

Depend on your budget. There're multiple solutions ready if you are willing to pay, e.g. [Urban Airship](http://urbanairship.com/)

I don't think you can force open popup on iOS if the screen is closed. In iOS the behavior of Push notification(**APN**) is entirely up to user. I could be wrong but that's my impression.

On Android(**GCM**) you can do that by faking popup in an Activity. Then wake the device from sleep to display the Activity.

If you are looking into news solution, be aware that both Android and iOS only allow 1,000 push devices per API call. So you will need to manage them yourself.

Comment: Urban airship now has a plan where the first 1M notifications/month are free.  See http://urbanairship.com/products/developer-edition